# Hide Content On Only Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, hide

I want the menu of my website(mobile/desktop) to look kinda like this one: http://www.panic.lv/en/ (except the HOME when mobile)
Desktop - show links "HOME", "WORKS", "ABOUT", and "CONTACTS" 
Mobile - no links, only logo

I followed [this instructions](http://ageekandhisblog.com/css-how-to-easily-hide-content-on-only-mobile-or-only-desktop/) but they don't seem to fully work.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul class="menu">
        <div id="home"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></div>
        <div id="works"><a href="workshome.html">WORKS</a></div>
        <div id="logo"></div>       
        <div id="about"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></div>
        <div id="contacts"><a href="contacts.html">CONTACTS</a></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  #wrapper {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    background-color: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-display: flex;
    -moz-display: flex;
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-display: flex;
    -moz-display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    padding: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
#home {
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    color: ghostwhite;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
}

#works {
    height: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    color: ghostwhite;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}


#about {
    height: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    color: ghostwhite;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;    
}


#contacts {
    height: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    color: ghostwhite;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
    } }
```

Comment: @media( size.... ) { .class : display none  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display: flex` to `display: none;` to your existing `.menu` rules to hide the menu.

Then, add this to your CSS file to turn it on above a certain screen size:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .menu {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

(the size, 1000px, is a filler. depending on whether you're talking just phones, or also tablets, or what, you'll have to change that)

**EDIT - The answer above is good for hiding an entire menu, I'm leaving it for anyone researching that simple option. The below is for the more specific parameters I overlooked from this question.**

Disregard the changes from the above answer.

If you want to do this with a minimum of changes to your code / additional HTML, you can simply add this to your CSS:

```
.menu div {
    display: none;
}
.menu div#logo {
    display: block; !important
}
@media (min-width: 991px) {
    .menu div {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

However, I strongly recommend that a more stable (and easier to edit later) solution would be to add `class="links"` to each `div` other than the logo and then use the following CSS:

```
.menu div.links {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 991px) {
    .menu div.links {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that and  the menu disappeared ! but i wanted the logo to stay visible too and that its not happening now because it is inside the .menu
That's why i was trying to hide just the links (#home, #works, #about and #contacts). I did this with the links but it didn't work as good, this made them invisible on the desktop too.

Comment: Okay, I overlooked that detail. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .menu{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: You misread. This is "show" only on mobile, they asked for "hide" only on mobile. You could change `min-width` to `max-width`, though my separate answer is more in line with typical "preferred practice."

Comment: Yes you're right didn't pay attention to the min-width and assumed was max-width

Comment: Code only answers are unlikely to be useful to either OP or future visitors. Please consider expanding your answer to include a explaination about why you think this is correct.